# C bug of 0.00 and -0.00

Tags: c, floating-accuracy

> C program to find the rank of the matrix.

I used the Gaussian elimination to determine the rank of the matrix. [This is the method which I have used.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computing_ranks_and_bases)

My code in c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define min(x,y) x>y?y:x

float** create_matrix(int,int);
void input(float**,int,int);
void display(float**,int,int);
void matrix_op(float**,int,int,int,float);
void row_trans(float**,int,int);
void row_swap(float**,int,int,int);
int rank(float**,int,int);

int main()
{
    int row,col;
    printf("Enter number of rows and columns: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&row,&col);
    float** matrix=create_matrix(row,col);
    input(matrix,row,col);
    printf("The rank of the matrix is: %d\n",rank(matrix,row,col));
    return 0;
}

float** create_matrix(int r,int c)
{
    int i;
    float** matrix=(float**)calloc(r,sizeof(float*));
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
        *(matrix+i)=(float*)calloc(c,sizeof(float));
    return matrix;
}

void input(float** matrix,int  r,int c)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            scanf("%f",&matrix[i][j]);
    }
}

void display(float** matrix,int  r,int c)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            printf("%.2f ",matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void matrix_op(float** matrix,int c,int j,int i,float scalar)
{
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<c;k++)
    {
        matrix[j][k]+=matrix[i][k]*scalar;
    }
}

void row_trans(float** matrix,int r,int i)
{
    if(matrix[i][i]!=0)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<r;j++)
        {
            if(j==i)
                continue;
            if(matrix[j][i]!=0)
                matrix_op(matrix,r,j,i,(-1.00)*(matrix[j][i]/matrix[i][i]));
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        int j=i+1;
        while(j<r)
        {
            if(matrix[j][i]==0)
                j+=1;
            else 
                break;
        }
        if(j!=r)
        {
            row_swap(matrix,r,i,j);
            row_trans(matrix,r,i);
        }
    }
}

void row_swap(float** matrix,int c,int i,int j)
{
    for(int k=0;k<c;k++)
    {
        float temp=matrix[i][k];
        matrix[i][k]=matrix[j][k];
        matrix[j][k]=temp;
    }
}

int rank(float** matrix,int r,int c)
{
    int i;
    int l=min(r,c);
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        row_trans(matrix,r,i);
        display(matrix,r,c);
        printf("\n");
    }
    i=r-1;
    while(i>=0)
    {
        if(matrix[i][l-1]==0)
            i-=1;
        else
            break;
    }
    return i+1;
}
```

When I input this:

```
Enter number of rows and columns: 5 5
3 -1 -2 3 -1
4 1 2 5 4
7 10 10 2 -3
2 -3 -6 1 -6
3 9 8 -3 -7
```

I get this:

```
3.00 -1.00 -2.00 3.00 -1.00 
0.00 2.33 4.67 1.00 5.33 
0.00 12.33 14.67 -5.00 -0.67 
0.00 -2.33 -4.67 -1.00 -5.33 
0.00 10.00 10.00 -6.00 -6.00 

3.00 -1.00 -2.00 3.00 -1.00 
0.00 2.33 4.67 1.00 5.33 
0.00 0.00 -10.00 -10.29 -28.86 
0.00 0.00 0.00 -0.00 -0.00 
0.00 0.00 -10.00 -10.29 -28.86 

3.00 -1.00 -2.00 3.00 -1.00 
0.00 2.33 4.67 1.00 5.33 
0.00 0.00 -10.00 -10.29 -28.86 
0.00 0.00 0.00 -0.00 -0.00 
0.00 0.00 0.00 -0.00 -0.00 

3.00 -1.00 -2.00 3.00 -1.00 
0.00 2.33 4.67 1.00 5.33 
0.00 0.00 -10.00 -10.29 -28.86 
0.00 0.00 0.00 -0.00 -0.00 
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 

3.00 -1.00 -2.00 3.00 -1.00 
0.00 2.33 4.67 1.00 5.33 
0.00 0.00 -10.00 -10.29 -28.86 
0.00 0.00 0.00 -0.00 -0.00 
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 

The rank of the matrix is: 4
```

Notice that **-0.00** and **0.00** are considered different.
And that is why I get rank as 4, whereas the rank should be 3.

Edit 1: In the final display we can see that, in the last column the second last row is **-0.00** and the last row is **0.00**. In the function `rank()` , the i is iterating over the zeroes of the last column and then it will return the `rows- #(zeroes)`. But it is not considering -0.00=0.00.

Edit 2: After using double I got the same problem. After debugging I got this,

```
115     while(i>=0)
(gdb) p i
$4 = 3
(gdb) n
117         if(matrix[i][l-1]==0)
(gdb) p matrix[i][l-1]
$5 = 8.8817841970012523e-16
(gdb) p matrix[i][l-1]==0
$6 = 0
```

Edit 3:
The problem is solved after introducing precision.

```
double set_prec(double n) 
{ 
    return floor(pow(10,3)*n)/pow(10,3); 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: _Notice that -0.00 and 0.00 are considered different._ Can you clarify that?

Comment: @DavidRanieri Two rows out of five are full of 0.00 or -0.00 hence the rank should be 3, but the rank given is 4, meaning that one of the rows (presumably the one with -0.00) is counted as a non-zero row.

Comment: Is this posible? as far as I know `(0.00f == -0.00f)` is `true`

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yeah, I just checked on my machine and they compared the same as well.

Comment: @gst, Even my compiler gives the same answer, but here I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Comparisons:  "According to the IEEE 754 standard, negative zero and positive zero should compare as equal with the usual (numerical) comparison operators, like the == operators of C and Java."

Comment: It is possible for a floating point number to be `-0`, since the common floating point encoding is sign magnitude. But it's also possible that those values aren't actually zero, just close to zero. For example, if `x = -0.0001` and you print `x` with `%.2f`, the output will be `-0.00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you print a number in C using `%.2f`, the C implementation rounds it to two decimal places. Numbers such as 0.003… or −0.0001… will be printed as `0.00` or `-0.00`. So the fact that a number is printed as `0.00` does not mean it is 0. From the behavior you report, it is clear the numbers you have in your program are not 0 or −0. (IEEE 754 arithmetic has a −0 that is mathematically 0 but retains the sign as information the programmer may use. It compares equal to +0.)

Floating-point arithmetic only approximates real-number arithmetic. When you use floating-point arithmetic in an ordinary way, any computed result `x` is only an approximation of the result *x* you would get using real-number arithmetic. Since you have only computed `x` and not *x*, you do not have complete information about what *x* is, and therefore it is **impossible**, without special analysis and design, to know exactly what *x* is. Therefore, if some result `x` is near 0, you cannot know whether *x* is 0 or not.

In general, the difference between the floating-pount result `x` and the raal-number result *x* can range from 0 to infinity or can even be “not a number.” In the particular case of doing Gaussian elimination with small matrices of small integer inputs, it might be possible to prove that floating-point results sufficiently near 0 correspond to results that would be 0 if computed with real-number arithmetic. In that case, treating results close to 0 as if they were 0 could produce correct results.

**This is not a correct solution in general, and rounding floating-point results to 0 or comparing with a tolerance should not be recommended in general.** It is only useful in particlar limited circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing to `0`, compare to *epsilon*

```
    double epsilon = 1E-12; // tweak as you deem fit
```

```
    //if (a != 0)
    if (fabs(a) > epsilon)
```

```
    //if (a == 0)
    if (fabs(a) < epsilon)
```

```
    //if (a == b)
    if (fabs(a - b) < epsilon)
```